# Is there a way to disable the Public IP for cloud_sql , while using Private IP via Deployment Manager

Tags: google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I am using deployment manager to deploy cloud_sql with private-ip, by default public IP is enabled for those deployment.

Is there a way to disable public IP using Deployment Manager ?

Answer (score 0):

Whether Public IP is enabled is controlled by the misleadingly named `settings.ipConfiguration.ipv4Enabled` property. If you set it to false, it should disable public IP connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

To disable public ip while deploying via deployment manager you can set the  **`settings.ipConfiguration.ipv4Enabled`** property to false in your yaml file. To see all the properties available, read the Cloud SQL documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances#settings.ipConfiguration.ipv4Enabled)

If you have deployed with the public ip and now want to disable it, use the below command:

> **gcloud sql instances patch [INSTANCE_NAME] --no-assign-ip**

To disable public ip using console or curl, please read the Google cloud  documentation for [disabling public ip](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip#disable-public)